# JNDI datasource error upgrading from Tomcat 7.0.23 to 7.0.27

Tags: hibernate, datasource, tomcat7, jndi

I'm trying to upgrade from Tomcat 7.0.23 to 7.0.27 (actually running Liferay). I'm getting the following exception when trying to access a datasource via Hibernate:

```
16:28:27,694 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-1][DatasourceConnectionProvider:110] Could not find datasource: java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySqlDS
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySqlDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
[...]
```

The exact same code runs fine in 7.0.23 (I can drop the WAR file in either instance).

Here is my $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml file (comments removed):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

  <Resource name="jdbc/MySqlDS" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="xxx"
            password="xxx"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xx?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true"
            maxActive="200" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            minIdle="3"
            testWhileIdle="true" testOnBorrow="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="120000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="600000"
            validationQuery="select 1"
        />
</Context>
```

The web.xml from the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HibernateServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.liferay.samplehibernate.servlet.HibernateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HibernateServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>
                /WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld
            </taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    <resource-ref>
            <description>data source</description>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/MySqlDS</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

And finally the the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Mappings -->
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySqlDS</property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <mapping
            resource="com/liferay/samplehibernate/model/FoodItem.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any suggestions about what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Did a bit more research. On vanilla versions of Tomcat 7.0.27 and the corresponding Liferay bundle, I can make a global definition using the same resource in server.xml. I can see the connection pool using [psi-probe](https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) and run queries. However, as soon as I introduce a resource-ref, either in the app or in the global web.xml, psi-probe complains that the resource is not configured correctly. Suggestions for next steps?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issues.